# switching hostname when I resolve IP address reversely via "nslookup" command

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname, nslookup

There's a network issue in my office so I ran `Look@LAN` application to check network condition of some windows PCs.

All of sudden, I found out a resolution of IP address of some PCs are switching continuously. Such as:

When I run `"nslookup 10.177.115.100"`, it switches between `krons-1234` and `krons-0987`.
Maybe there is a hostname conflict in cache. Am I right ?

If not, what could cause this kind of hostname switching and how to fix it ?

Please give me some advice how to approach to solve this case.

Also, I do not have any rights to access DNS servers and other network devices at all.

Comment: If you don't have accces to those services, who has? Are you in charge of your network? If not, ask the one who is, because it's his job to fix this.

Comment: "I'm not responsible for the network, but I'm going to meddle around with it because I think there's a problem that needs to be fixed. In addition, I'm going to install and run whatever software I can find and download from the internet that I think will help me solve this problem. All the while I'll be avoiding the people who are responsible for the network because what I'm doing falls outside the bounds of my responsibility and authority."

Answer (score 5):

As SvenW and joeqwerty have said, this is pretty obviously not your job (as evidenced by the fact that you have no access to the things you would need to change to fix the problem) -- **Contact Your System/Network Administrator**, report the problem with as much detail as you can, and then leave them alone so they can do their job.

The *most likely* cause of the behavior you are seeing is that two PTR records exist for the IP in question (though this is by no means the *only possible* cause).  If this is indeed the problem it is a matter for your DNS administrator to fix, and is not something you can do yourself without access to the DNS server.